# Constructing a vector of string_views from an initializer_list

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I'm trying to construct a `vector` of `string_view`s from an `initializer_list< const char * >` which worked okay on GCC 9, but after updating to GCC 10 it crashes during runtime.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::string_view > const v { { "Before.", "Afterrrrrr." } };
    printf( "%s %zu\n", v[0].data(), v[0].length() );
    printf( "%s %zu\n", v[1].data(), v[1].length() );

    return 0;
}
```

Clang also handles the code okay, what gives?

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/6s1c61

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this variable definition

```
std::vector< std::string_view > const v { { "Before.", "Afterrrrrr." } };
```

you accidentally used this new C++20 `string_view` constructor:

```
template<class It, class End>
constexpr basic_string_view(It first, End last);
```

So, you only construct *one* `string_view` using the start of `"Afterrrrrr."`
as the end iterator. This makes the program have undefined behavior.

This would be the proper way:

```
std::vector< std::string_view > const v { "Before.", "Afterrrrrr." };
```

Comment: The problem also consequetly disappears with `-std=c++17`. The constructor was added into libstdc++ in [this commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/8857080c81761eb1344c3b5404b5e25e9cc949eb), which implements [P1391R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1391r4.pdf).